# Ansible download mysql server binary

Tags: ansible

I am trying to download the mysql server binary via [Ansible uri module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html) and it is failing.

> TASK [mysql : Download MySQL Server]
>
> ---
>
> fatal: [server1 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"cache_control": "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store", "changed": false, "connection": "close", "content_length": "4530", "content_type": "text/html", "date": "Thu, 27 Apr 2023 10:27:05 GMT", "elapsed": 0, "etag": ""46491460e504640b96a3f5e60da0945f:1434117667"", "expires": "Thu, 27 Apr 2023 10:27:05 GMT", "msg": "Status code was 403 and not [200]: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden", "path": "/home//code//roles/mysql/files/mysql-8.0.30-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64.tar.xz", "pragma": "no-cache", "redirected": false, "server": "AkamaiNetStorage", "set_cookie": "AK_NETWORKTYPE=ESSL; expires=Thu, 27-Apr-2023 10:29:05 GMT", "status": 403, "url": "https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-8.0/mysql-8.0.30-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64.tar.xz"}

My Ansible task

```
  uri:
     url: https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-8.0/mysql-8.0.30-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64.tar.xz
     method: GET
     follow_redirects: safe
     dest: /some/path/
```

I have also tried all allowable values for the follow_redirects.

I was able to get the download to work via curl on the command line

```
curl -L https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-8.0/mysql-8.0.30-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64.tar.xz
```

Not sure what else to try.  Any ideas?

Comment: You would need to compare the request made by `curl` with the request made by Ansible. Alternately, rewrite your playbook to run `curl` in a `command` task rather than using the `uri` module.

Comment: from the [tag:ansibile]: "Installing Ansible and prerequisites, connection issues, ... are off-topic."

Comment: @Luuk - so my question wouldn't qualify as "using the tool"?  I think they meant connection issue such as reaching out to one of the nodes you are trying to run something on.

Comment: @Crackerman; The description of the tag is not (very) clear about that.   the link between you r ansible task, which uses `'{{ mysql_server_download_url }}'` and the provided links seems to suggest some info is missing from your ansible task. How does ansible know where `mysql_server_download_url` is, and what version to install?

Comment: @Luuk - I didn't post the entire role because you would be scrolling for miles.  The variable is set in the molecule yaml file.  I changed the role to remove the variables that are being used.  The issue is that the uri module is not following the redirect like curl is.

Comment: @Luuk connection problems in the tag description refer to connection from the ansible controller to the target server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `uri` module for downloading content. use `get_url` instead.

problem is from mysql download site. seems they are filtering on `user-agent`.

this task will work:

```yaml
  - get_url:
      headers:
        user-agent: curl/7.81.0          ## for instance here i set curl user agent
      url: 'https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-8.0/mysql-8.0.30-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64.tar.xz'
      dest: /tmp/test.txz
```

Comment: 1) there's no need to change the module (although it is ok). Changing the user agent works with `uri` as well. 2) there's a dedicated `http_agent` parameter which should be used instead of setting the header directly.